# Why is it that I need not convert int to string in this case? (.Net)

Tags: .net, messagebox

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 5;
    MessageBox.Show(i);
}
```

Fails..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 5;
    MessageBox.Show("hoo" + i);
}
```

Works. Why is that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show()` requires a string as its input parameter.

The first sample fails because there is no implicit conversion from integer to string.

The second sample succeeds because `"hoo" + i` evaluates to a string. This happens because the C# language defines an addition operator which accepts a `string` and an `object`. The `object` is converted to a `string` by calling `ToString()`. This string addition operator is always selected when one of the operands to the addition is a `string`.

Comment: You're going too fast.  The + operator gets translated to string.Concat().  Which has overloads that accept Object.  Which use ToString().

Comment: @Hans Yeah, I don't know the precise terminology in C#.

Comment: @Hans Actually, David's wording is the most accurate. The .NET string type does not have an addition operator, but the language provides one. (See link in my answer.) The spec doesn't mention Concat, which only has overloads that have all string or all object arguments.

Comment: @HansPassant see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx They just talk the same David just mentioned above.Yup the underlying process must be string.Concat of course..

Comment: What version of David's answer do you mean ;)  But we agree, the compiler has hard-coded knowledge of Concat().

Comment: the previous version! :) David pls revert back to old one, it was perfect! :) Now im thinking of voting for someone else :)

Comment: @nawful I don't mind which answer you accept. I think this one more directly answers the question. As to how `"hoo" + i` evaluates to string, that's somewhat secondary.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I wouldnt have posted this question without knowing "hoo" + i translating to an equivalent string. Anyone knows that. My question "why" was precisely to know the underlying power of "+" operator. Which you answered. But now you edited to a simple thing any layman would know. But its your wish ultimately :)

Comment: @nawfal I've tried to compromise to meet everyone's requests. But I'm getting a little tired. I think I'll stop now!!  ;-)

Comment: Hehe, supporting the Right Answer can be hard work at SO.  Pop a beer, awesome answers again today, goodnight :)

Answer (score 3):

Your first code snippet doesn't work for obvious reasons. The `.Show` method expects a string and you are passing it an integer.

There's a [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx) method that you can use:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 5;
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

Now let's consider the following snippet:

```
int i = 5;
MessageBox.Show("hoo" + i);
```

that's actually translated by the compiler to:

```
int i = 5;
MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("hoo", i));
```

which is basically the following [`.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx) overload taking 2 objects as arguments and returning string as result. And because the `MessageBox.Show` method expects a string it works as that's what the `.Concat` method I have shown you returns.

Comment: @nawfal, what did I got wrong? I have explained what happens in the second case when you use this `+` operator and why it works. Isn't what you wanted to know? Why does the second work and first not?

Comment: @David Heffernan, ah, yeah, the edit indeed. The important is the quality of the end product that you get, not how is it being made :-)

Comment: @Darin In a C# question like this, if you don't get upvotes within the first 2 minutes, your answer ends up languishing 4 pages down from the top, so I understand the process!!

Comment: @David Heffernan I really don't give s..t about votes and reputation. What I care is contribute to the community with quality answers. It's the only thing that matters to me.

Comment: OK fine. I actually think that SO would be better if answers were hidden for the first 15 minutes (say), so that all the grace period editing could be done in private and one could present a well-formed answer without it being drowned out.

Comment: @David Heffernan, no I don't agree. The fact that I am slow in my edits, doesn't excuse me. The fact that someone else provided a better answer faster than me is perfectly normal, that person deserves all the upvotes. It's up to the responsibility of the person casting his vote to decide which answer he thinks is better. That's his own right. As I said, personally I don't care about this stuff. I focus on the quality of my answer and that's all that matters to me.

Answer (score 3):

The second version is converted to a call to [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx), which accepts any two objects and returns a string. It is as if you had written this:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("hoo", i));
```

Comment: The use of Concat is an implementation detail and as such has nothing to do with _why_ the code compiles. That's in the language spec, which doesn't mention Concat at all.

Answer (score 2):

The + operator is overloaded for System.String. If one operand is a string, the other can be any object, and ToString() will be called on that object first.

So in the first call, the result is an integer, which cannot be converted implicitly to a string. In the second call, the + operator is called, and the integer is converted to a string, returning in a string.

Source: [Section 7.7.4 of the C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because in your second example, `("hoo" + i)` is interpreted as a string, and your first example passes an `int` to a string parameter.  Execute this code to prove that:

```
Console.WriteLine((5).GetType());
Console.WriteLine(("hoo" + 5).GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageBox.Show()` method accepts parameter of string type only. In your first case, the parameter is of type `int` and there's no implicit conversion between `int` and `string`. And the code is not compilabel.

In the second case, `int` is converted to string thanks to the `+` operator defined for `string`. Here used for concatenation - it works this way when one of the parameteres for `+` is of type `string`. So the parameter is automatically converted to `string` and the code works. And the result is `string`.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox` doesn't know what to do with an `int` as an argument in your first piece of code.  But rather it is expecting a string and the string can concat that int to itself via operator+.  The `MessageBox.Show()` can then take that concatenated string and display it.